# Delete all entries of an element of a list in Elixir (not just the first one)

Tags: list, elixir, removing-whitespace

I found  [`List.delete/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/List.html#delete/2), that deletes only the first entry searched. I was looking for something that deletes all the entries, like

```
[:a, :b, :c, :a, :a]
|> List.delete_all :a

[:b, :c]
```

Is there something like that? Perhaps something like `List.delete_all/2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [`Enum.reject/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html#reject/2)

```rb
Enum.reject(~w|a b c a a|a, & &1 == :a)
#⇒ [:b, :c]
```

---

*Sidenote:* using pipe for the single operation is considered an anti-pattern by Elixir core team.

---

Another (more flexible) possibility would be to use [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html#reduce/2):

```rb
~w|a b c a a|a
|> Enum.reduce([],
     &(if &1 == :a, do: &2, else: [&1 | &2]))
|> :lists.reverse()
#⇒ [:b, :c]
```

---

More erlangish (and elegant) approach would be to use recursion:

```rb
defmodule M do
  def get_rid_of(e, list, acc \\ [])
  def get_rid_of(_, [], acc),
    do: :list.reverse(acc)
  def get_rid_of(e, [e | rest], acc),
    do: get_rid_of(e, rest, acc)
  def get_rid_of(e, [o | rest], acc),
    do: get_rid_of(e, rest, [o | acc])
end
M.get_rid_of :a, ~w|a b c a a|a
#⇒ [:b, :c]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
[:a, :b, :c, :a, :a] |> Enum.reject( fn x -> x == :a end )
```

gives

```
[:b, :c]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [comprehensions](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/comprehensions.html) with a filter:

```elixir
iex(1)> for x <- [:a, :b, :c, :a, :a], x !== :a, do: x
[:b, :c]
```

Or use a guard instead of the filter:

```elixir
iex(2)> for x when x !== :a <- [:a, :b, :c, :a, :a], do: x
[:b, :c]
```

Comment: This should be chosen as a correct answer.

Answer (score -2):

```
list = list -- list
```

This will remove all elements in list and list will be empty - `[]`